# Find if a collection of objects have the same value for a given attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two related models : `Invoice` and `Currency`.

`Invoice belongs_to Currency` and `Currency has_many Invoices`

I have a table which displays the list of every invoices and I am able to filter them by currency. An invoice also has a `price`field and I have a method which calculates the total price of invoices I display.

My problem is that I want to display the total price if and only if every invoices have the same currency.

I am pretty sure there is a simple way to achieve this but I can't find it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact, there are many ways to achieve that, e.g, you can check if all of them have the same currency this way:

```
invoices.reject {|inv| inv.currency_id == invoices[0].currency_id}.empty?
```

or

```
invoices.map {|inv| inv.currency_id}.uniq.length == 1
```

Comment: I would test `inv.currency_id` instead of asking Rails to translate every Currency as Ruby object and then get their id. Generates a little bit less DB Queries

Comment: There are many ways to do it, but both your proposals are a little obtuse because they test the cardinality of some other transformation instead of just asking if everything is the same.  This seems a more direct way to compose the test: `invoices.all?{ |inv| inv.currency_id == invoices.first.currency_id }`

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way to ask if everything in a collection is the same is to ask if all elements equal the first one:

```
invoices.all?{ |inv| inv.currency_id == invoices.first.currency_id }
```

If you do this thing a lot, one might consider extended Enumerable with a convenience method:

```
module Enumerable
  def all_same?
    v = first
    all? {|e| e == v}
  end
end

invoices.map(&:currency_id).all_same?
```

Comment: That's exactly the question I was asking myself. Thanks for the tip.